# Separate numbers with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple table which the data is being generated using loop, I have problem with generating the random numbers What I want is to generated saparately using `div` ex. `<td>09897</td>` to `<td><div>0</div><div>0</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>7</div></td>` I manage to generate the numbers somehow, but dont know how to separate them.

Hope you help me.

Thanks

```js
var dataNum = 30;

for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

  $('table tbody').append('<tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>');
    } else if (j == 1) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000) + '</td>');
    }
  }
  $('table tbody').append('</tr>');

}



function todayDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('');
}

function deci(number) {
  var num = null;
  if (number < 10) {
    num = '000' + number;
  } else if (number > 9 && number < 100) {
    num = '00' + number;
  } else if (number > 99 && number < 1000) {
    num = '0' + number;
  } else {
    num = number;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```css
table th, table td{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th>Random</th>
    </tr>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to convert your generated number to desired `html` and then insert it in your `td` tag (`convert("09897", "div")`):

```
function convert(num, tag){return "<"+tag+">"+(num+"").split("").join("</"+tag+"><"+tag+">")+"</"+tag+">"}
```

Answer (score 1):

So `(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000)` gives you the random number. Now you need each of the digit (which would be available via `.toString().split("")`), and then for every digit you need to wrap `<div>` around it - which can be done via `.map(t => "<div>" + t + "</div>")`. Then you can join those strings using `.join("")`.

```js
var dataNum = 30;

for (let t = 1; t <= dataNum; t++) {

  $('table tbody').append('<tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + todayDate() + '-' + deci(t) + '</td>');
    } else if (j == 1) {
      $('table tbody').append('<td>' + 
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 90000)
      .toString()
      .split("")
      .map(t => "<div>" + t + "</div>")
      .join("") + 
      '</td>');
    }
  }
  $('table tbody').append('</tr>');

}



function todayDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('');
}

function deci(number) {
  var num = null;
  if (number < 10) {
    num = '000' + number;
  } else if (number > 9 && number < 100) {
    num = '00' + number;
  } else if (number > 99 && number < 1000) {
    num = '0' + number;
  } else {
    num = number;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```css
table th,
table td {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th>Random</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

References:

String#split - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Array#join - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Array#map - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=90987;
x=x.toString();
for(var y=0; y<x.length; y++)
{
    console.log(x[y]);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation with your, code, since its not always self explanatory